# tfs.visualstudio.com log in download all source code

Tags: visual-studio-team-services

We have our source code hosted on `tfs.visualstudio.com`. One of the directors wants to be able to download a complete cut of the code once per week.

Is there anyway they can do this direct from the site, without them having Visual Studio installed?

Please note this is Team Foundation Service - Visual Studio hosted with Microsoft (not on our own servers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this myself, though it was so easy.
This is the way to do it:

- Login to hosted tfs
- click code
- click explorer
- right click project root
- click download as zip